# Proving a theorem on integration to the limit

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I'm working my way through Durrett's notes on probability theory and have come across a proof that I don't quite understand. The proof statement is:

Suppose $X_n \to X$ a.s. Let g, h be continuous functions with:

(i) $g \geq 0$ and $g(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$

$(i i)|h(x)| / g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$
and

(iii) $\operatorname{Eg}\left(X_{n}\right) \leq K<\infty$ for all $n$

Then $\operatorname{Eh}\left(X_{n}\right) \rightarrow \operatorname{Eh}(X)$

The proof begins by saying that we should "pick $M$ large so that $P(|X| = M) = 0$. I don't understand why we know that this is possible; it seems like we haven't imposed enough conditions on $X$ to know that we can do this?

Comment: There can only be countably many values $m$ with $P(|X|=m)>0$, so if $X$ is a continuous random variable, there should be many values of $M$ left over.

Comment: So this doesn't necessarily hold for $X$ discrete? I just re-read the last few pages and nowhere did it state that assumption..

Comment: Seems to me that $P(X=m)=\frac1{m(m+1)}$ is a counterexample.